# (Angular 5) *ngIf not working on Select/Options

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a model Questionaire which has name property.

*app.component.ts*

```
import {Questionaire} from '../questionaire.model';

questionaire : Questionaire;
```

Based on the name property of class Questionaire in my html code I need to display different option value of the select element using *ngIf this is
what I am trying to do in *app.component.html*

```
<select 
 class="form-control" 
 name="proposal" 
 required 
 ngModel
 >
   <div *ngIf = "questionaire.name === 'credit'">
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="Proposal">Proposal</option>
     <option value="ndg">NDG</option>
     <option value="credit">Credit Line</option>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf = "questionaire.name === 'asset'">
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="Proposal">Proposal</option>
     <option value="asset">Asset</option> 
   </div>
 </select>
```

I am not able to achieve what I am trying to do.

I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using *ngIf on a div i used it on a ng-container and it worked for me.

Here is the piece of code:

```
<select 
 class="form-control" 
 name="proposal" 
 required 
 ngModel
 >
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="Proposal">Proposal</option>
   <ng-container *ngIf = "questionaire.name === 'credit'">
     <option value="ndg">NDG</option>
     <option value="credit">Credit Line</option>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf = "questionaire.name === 'asset'">
     <option value="asset">Asset</option> 
   </ng-container>

</select>
```

I hope it may help.

Answer (score 4):

You should really move your data logic inside the typescript part of your component. Your template should only contain presentation logic

```
public interface Kvp {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  questionaire : Questionaire;
  options: Kvp[];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.questionnaire.name === 'credit') {
      this.options = [
        {value: 'Proposal', label: 'Proposal'},
        {value: 'ndg', label: 'NDG'}
      ];
      // You can do the rest ;-)
    }
  }

}
```

Then, inside your template, simply iterate through "options"

```
<select class="form-control" 
   name="proposal" 
   required 
   ngModel>
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option *ngFor="let item from options" value="{{item.label}}">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

**note:** You really shouldn't have any business logic inside your AppComponent. This component should only contain sub-components.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your detailed answer. It is indeed a solution for a Reactive Approach (Angular Form) But i am using a Template driven approach instead. Could you give me a solution on TD approach thank you in advance!

Comment: @AdnanAbdulKhaliq Hello, I don't think that because you have chosen a module instead of another, you should have all your business logic inside your template.

Comment: @Debalton Hi, Yes you are very right. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-template instead of Div like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="proposal" required ngModel *ngIf="questionaire.name === 'credit' else asset ">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Proposal">Proposal</option>
    <option value="ndg">NDG</option>
    <option value="credit">Credit Line</option>
</select>
<ng-template #asset>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="Proposal">Proposal</option>
    <option value="asset">Asset</option>
</ng-template>
```